# No-route with all magento grid/listing

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, file-permissions, noroute

I am having problem when moving to new server use Ubuntu.
All my controller when loading grid/listing using UI component  goes to 404 with no-route:

That is example:

```
domain.com/wondergopher/admin/noroute/index/key/1dc2621593818c8437bda5d4cd3e747a1759782801db68ce1a41a2d88a2ef544/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:
404
Version:HTTP/1.1
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Example product grid:
[image]
Also, I don't see any log/error via  folder var/ so that is difficult to check. 
Anyone know this issues can help me?

Comment: you remove the log/error and var/cache folder after check error log and exception.log

Comment: @MohitPatel I have tried however it doesn't appear any error

Comment: you run all commands ??

Comment: yes, I have run upgrade, deploy, permission again... nothing success

Comment: you please check network tag in repose tab error

Comment: @thelight, Have you got a solution for this issue, Any tips to solve this issue.